# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.1'

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, code-signing, codesign

I know this question has asked many times. But none of them helped me solve my issue. I am testing my app on Ipod. Its working perfectly fine.But when i go for **Profile**(To Check any memory leaks) it throws me the following error

```
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.1'
```

Which works when i am testing with Simulator?

I am really confused about what is going here?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please put screen shot of your build settings?. Something wrong there. Are you normally able to install on device? Please also check if your provisional profile expired or not selected in Debug and Release in build settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I forget to add provisional in Release.. Now working like charm..+1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your provisioning profile is properly loaded. You may need to redownload from Apple Developer's website and reinstall the .mobileprovision file.

Also be sure to set the Release and Debug signing identities in Summary Info to the proper settings after you reinstall/install the proper profile.

For release you'd want to use distro and for debug you want to use your developer. Also be sure your device is properly being used for development. You may need to go to organizer in xcode and reconfig.